# Google Cloud Platform Tensorboard - No dashboards are currently active

Tags: google-app-engine, object, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

I was working on the tensorflow object detection API. I managed to train it locally on my computer and get decent results. However, when I tried to replicate the same on GCP, I had several errors. So, basically, I followed the documentation mentioned in the official tensorflow -running on cloud documentation

So this is how the bucket is laid out:

1. [Bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W425c.png)
2. [weeddetectin-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxHAg.png)
3. [Train-packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu3rK.png)

This is how I ran the training and evaluation job:

1. [Running a multiworker training job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk9t4.png)
2. [Running an evaluation job on cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVVA7.png)

I then used the following command to monitor on tensoboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir=gs://weeddetection --port=8080
```

I opened the dashboard using the preview feature in the console. But it says no dashboards are active for the current data set. 
[No Dashboards are active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urOdE.png)

So, I checked on my activity page to really see if the training and evaluation job were submitted:

1. [Training Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opLNe.jpg)
2. [Evaluation Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vh2g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there are no events files being written to your bucket.
The root cause could be that the manual your are using refers to an old version of the tensor models.

Please try and change

```
 --train_dir=gs:...
```

to

```
 --model_dir=gs://${YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}/model
```

And resend the job, once the job is running check the model_dir in the bucket to see if the files are written there.

Check out: [gcloud ml-engine jobs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training#USER_ARGS) for additional read.

Hope it help!